# Differentiate MySQL and Sphinx searchd

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx, sphinxql

I'm running Sphinx searchd server on ports 9312 and 9306 (mysql41) and I connect to the server with the following code to use SphinxQL:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database, "9306");
```

When I send a SQL statement, it gives me results and everything is working fine (apparently), but if I change the port from 9306 to any other number (for example 1111), it is still giving me results, so I have no way to check if I'm really connecting to the searchd daemon at port 9306 or I'm still connecting to the mysql server at port 3306.

Any ideas?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: You shouldn't get results if you enter a bunk port... are you checking `$mysqli->connect_errno` and `$mysqli->connect_error` to see if it just seems like you are getting results?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/mysqli_get_server_info

Should be a reliable method :)

But do also see
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-mysql-version-string